# Using Merge with Trigger in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-trigger

I am facing a problem related to merge statement I have merge statement like this

```
MERGE abc A 
USING xyz B ON A.trans_date = b.trans_date 

WHEN matched AND B.trans_date IS NOT NULL 
   THEN 
       UPDATE 
          SET A.column1 = B.column1, 
              A.column2 = B.column2, 
              A.column3 = B.column3 

WHEN NOT matched BY target AND B.trans_date IS NOT NULL 
   THEN 
      INSERT (column1, column2, column3) 
      VALUES (column1, column2, column3);
```

And having a trigger on table ABC like this

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[TRG_ABC] 
ON [dbo].[Z_ABC] 
FOR UPDATE 
AS 
    DECLARE @Column4 NUMERIC(9), @Column5 CHAR(1)

    SELECT @Column4 = Column4, @Column5 = Column5 
    FROM inserted 

    UPDATE ABC 
    SET Column5 = CASE 
                     WHEN @Column5 = 'S' 
                        THEN 'Y' 
                        ELSE CASE
                                WHEN @Column5 = 'N' 
                                   THEN 'N' 
                                   ELSE 'U' 
                             END
                  END 
    WHERE Column4 = @Column4
```

This trigger is not working for updating each row. Is there any wrong with code or any solution for updating each row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Sql Server, `Trigger` will be called at statement level not row level. So the `Inserted` magic table will have all the updated/inserted records.

Alter the trigger like this

```
UPDATE a
SET    Column5 = CASE
                   WHEN Column5 = 'S' THEN 'Y'
                   WHEN Column5 = 'N' THEN 'N'
                   ELSE 'U'
                 END
FROM   ABC a
       INNER JOIN inserted i
               ON i.Column4 = a.Column4
```

Answer (score 2):

Code within Triggers should contain SET based operations

You have declared variables, this will cause use of only the last affected row data

So your inner UPDATE will cause faulty results

You can refer to usage of [merge command in trigger](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/sql-merge-command-for-summary-table.aspx)